# find volume using Cavalieri - difficult integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$B_n(0,1)$ is the $n$ dimensional ball, centered at zero with radius one.

We define the set $P_n = \{x \in B_n: |x_1| < \frac{1}{1000}\}$. Find $v(P_n)$.

What I did:

Notice that the intersection of $P_n$ with the plane $x_1 = t$ is well defined for $t \in (-\frac{1}{1000}, \frac{1}{1000})$ and that $P_n \cap\{x \in \mathbb R^n: x = t\} = \{x \in \mathbb R^n: x_2^2+x_3^2+ \dots +x_n^2 < 1-t^2\} =B_{n-1}(0,\sqrt{1-t^2})$.

Now from Cavalieri's principle:

$$v(P_n) = \int_{P_n} 1 \, dx = \int_{-\frac{1}{1000}}^{\frac{1}{1000}}\int_{B_{n-1}(0,\sqrt{1-t^2})} 1 \, dx \, dt = v(B_{n-1}(0,1))\int_{-\frac{1}{1000}}^{\frac{1}{1000}}(1-t^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\,dt$$

How would we calculate this integral?

Comment: Substitute t = $\sin(\theta)$ into the integral, and use a identity for the integral of $\cos(\theta)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll elaborate on @user458276's comment: For an integral $\int_{-a}^a (1 - t^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \mathrm{d}t$ first substitute $t = \sin\theta$ to obtain

$$\int_{-a}^a (1 - t^2)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \mathrm{d}t = \int_{-\arcsin a}^{\arcsin a} (\cos^2 \theta)^\frac{n-1}{2} \cos \theta \,\mathrm{d} \theta = 2 \int_0^{\arcsin a} \cos^n \theta \, \mathrm{d} \theta$$

Then take a look at a [list of trig integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_only_sine) and find

$$ \int \cos^n \theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta = \frac1{n} \cos^{n-1}\theta \,\sin\theta - \frac{n-1}{n}\int \cos^{n-2} \theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Since $n$ is an integer repeatedly applying this expression will lead to a known integral ($\int \mathrm{d}\theta$ for even $n$ and $\int\cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta$ for odd $n$).